# 'Bottom' Gravity in XML Layout not Working

Tags: android, xml

I have a simple XML Layout, in which I would like to place a Button in the bottom right corner.
I first tried `android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"` 
However, the result was the button gravitating toward the right side, but not the bottom.

I then tried "center" and that worked, but it remained unchanged in combination with "bottom".

It appears that something is stopping  the button from gravitating to the bottom.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what `layout_height` have parent of this `Button`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Layout in which the button is placed has a gravity attribute, which will give you this effect. Eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="bottom|right">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem in this project, but in future projects, how would I go about having the layout fill the entire screen so that I could have one Button Gravitated "top |left" and another "top | right". I don't mean to be chatty, I just see this coming up in future projects.

Comment: The part ...android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"... should make sure it takes the whole space. If you need to have that overlaid with other things, use a FrameLayout with different frames on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the layout where you are placing this button does not go to the bottom of the screen.

Use [hierarchyviewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) to see what is happening. And the code posted by Cesar should give you something actually working...

Answer (score 1):

Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.  Not only does it *really* do what you want, but it actually uses less processing and displays more quickly than LinearLayout.

Instead of a LinearLayout, define your space with a RelativeLayout like:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
```

Then, to put your button at the bottom right, add this to your button:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
/>
```

Cheers,
-scott

PS: as always, I haven't tested this code, just typing in as I remember things.